# Getting a running android.media.MediaPlayer to persist across activities in an Application

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I'm trying to show a video stream that starts in one activity of my application and follows the user to other activities in the application without having to re-prepare it.  A bit of a pause on activity change is OK, but it shouldn't restart.  Everything's working fine in one activity, but when switching activities the `MediaPlayer` doesn't seem to want to connect to the new `SurfaceHolder`.  The audio works beautifully though, with barely a hitch.

I've been trying to do this via a subclass of `SurfaceView` initialized with the application context. (Re-siting application-context views across activities seems to work fine when I instead use simple views such as `Button`, so I think that's not the problem.) In the constructor I create the MediaPlayer object, set the listeners and datasource (an MP4 stream via HTTP--and yeah, I verified that I can play it with a normal usage of MediaPlayer), and call `prepareAsync`. In my `SurfaceHolder.Callback`'s `surfaceCreated` method I call `setDisplay` and (if the player has finished preparing) `start`. In the `surfaceDestroyed` method I call `pause`. And in the prepare callback if the surface has already been created I call start.

I'm at a loss of what to do at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: I've also tried with a local video file to reduce the number of things that might be going wrong. Same results.

Comment: If someone has an example of a <code>MediaPlayer</code> use that can continue playing video through an orientation change, that would probably include what I need to make this work. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any such online.

Comment: could you share your some code for help I am also in same sort of trouble but unable to get the view at other activities..Here is my Running code Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739386/android-how-to-obtain-media-player-progress-bar-and-also-how-to-show-it-on-each-a

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to store the position in the method onpause():

```
public void onPause(){

     super.onPause();
     int pos = player.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

and then in the new activity call:

```
player.seekTo(pos);

player.start();
```

But that isn´t very efficient. It would be nice to store the status of the video when leaving the activity and restoring when return to it, but I can´t find anything like this online.

Comment: Pausing and resuming works fine for me, since I maintain a single instance across the activities. The problem is with reattaching it to a surface.